# What should I consider when choosing a pocket door system?

Tags: pocket-door

I am considering installing a few pocket doors in our “inner hallway”, these will be behind built-in bookshelf’s.   Ideally I wish to reuse our heaver weight 1930 doors, as they match the rest of the home.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of pocket door appraches. Usually is makes sense to buy a frame kit such as this one

[image: pocket door frame]

There are many grades and sizes, some of which are meant for [heavy doors](http://www.johnsonhardware.com/2000.htm). You do need to make sure that the thickness of your doors do not exceed the limits of the kits. If they do, you may be able to buy parts and create your own combination that will suit. Also, there are standard heights, which could be adjusted for (e.g., with bottom blocking) if your doors are especially tall.

There are other brands that may provide additional features, such as [this one](http://www.hafele.com/us/products/12380.asp) which has a color matched header insert, and [this one](http://www.pocketdoors.net/pocket-door-frame-kits/crowder-pocket-door-kit/k-n-crowder-type-c-pocket-door-track-and-hardware.html) which can be used in thicker walls , and perhaps with thicker doors.

Comment: As the pockets doors will be between the currnet brick wall and the new built in bookcase, I don't think a framekit will be the dest option

Comment: @walker Actually, the split framing portion of the kit (the upright metal with wood inserts) help to keep the door from swaying as it is rolled into the wall and may prevent it banging the brick. You also could just buy the head rails and rollers and work out your own side buffers.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider that pocket doors rattle, if air pressure changes due to window or HVAC.